# Kubeflow on Azure - Can't run a pipeline

Tags: azure, kubernetes, docker-volume, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I installed Kubeflow on Azure following this [Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20210418010913/https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/k8s/kfctl-istio-dex/)

However, when I create an experiment and then try to run Taxi Pipeline, the following error appears: *MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "docker-sock" : hostPath type check failed: /var/run/docker.sock is not a socket file*

What am I missing?

I read the following links but still can't understand how to solve it

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/826

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/3500

[Kubeflow pipeline fail to create container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989018/kubeflow-pipeline-fail-to-create-container)

https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/issues-with-running-argo-against-microk8s-on-ubunte/13553/3

I tried setting up a PersistentVolume but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Executing  `kubectl edit configmap workflow-controller-configmap -n kubeflow` and changing to   `containerRuntimeExecutor: k8sapi`  was the solution